# One click force delete unsaved images in Preview

Tags: preview

I have made many screenshots and pasted into Preview and do not want to walk through the "Save" dialog for each one

[image]

Yes I could click on `Delete` (or tab five times as I end up doing instead) but I am a keyboardist and after doing this many dozens of times I'd rather use a quick keyboard shortcut . Is there any such animal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> brings up this prompt for me:

[image: popup]

Then click: **Delete and Quit**

Comment: Thx that's what I needed.

Comment: To enable selecting the "delete and quit" button as seen in the screenshot: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > check "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls". Use tab to select a button, and spacebar to "click" it

Answer (score 1):

I have a variation on the OP's question.
I have a screenshot open in Preview that I do not want to save.
Currently, to close it without saving, I have to press CMD+W, then click on the Delete button.
Like the OP, I am a "keyboardist", but even if I enable "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls", I have to tab 11 times to move focus to the Delete button.
Is there any keyboard command that will simply "close this window without saving"?